# how to create Dynamic check-box list with 3 options in C#

Tags: c#, checkbox, .net-3.5

[image: CheckBox list for languages skills]

I need to create check-box list dynamically populated from database.
I have no problem with creating this with the single option but with 3 - kind of puzzle me.
Currently I have following code which create single colum of checkboxes with Language name:

```
public void CreateCheckBox(DataSet DSDataForCheckBox, string pLangGrp)
{
    CheckBoxList chkList = new CheckBoxList();
    chkList.ID = "LanguageList";
    chkList.AutoPostBack = true;
    chkList.DataSource = DSDataForCheckBox;
    chkList.DataTextField = "LangName";
    chkList.DataValueField = "LangID";
    chkList.DataBind();

    Panel pLang = new Panel();

    if (pLangGrp != "")
    {
        pLang.GroupingText = pLangGrp;

    }
    else
    {
        pLang.GroupingText = "Non Assigned Group";

    }
    pLang.Controls.Add(chkList);
    this.Form.Controls.Add(pLang);

}
```

Need your experts help.
Thanks

PS: we are on NET 3.5, so many options from 4.0 is not available for me.

Comment: You will have to create your own control. There is no .Net control which will provide that functionality out of the box or you use 3 list boxes and put them next to each other. I would recommend the first option :-)

Comment: Are you using winforms or web application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can achieve this using repeater control or any list based control.

This is just to provide some idea to start with and you can do research to fit to your requirement.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" EnableViewState="False">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>

                <tr>
                    <td class="RowStyle"><%# Eval("LangName") %></td>
                    <td>

                        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkListLangs" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="R" Value="R"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="W" Value="W"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="S" Value="S"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:CheckBoxList>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Code behind** to get the selected values:

```
protected void btnSubmitLangs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
    {
      CheckBoxList chkListLanguages = (CheckBoxList)item.FindControl("chkListLangs");

      List<ListItem> selectedLangs = chkListLanguages.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                                     .Where(listItem => listItem.Selected)
                                     .ToList();
      //Or you can use foreach loop also to get the selected items.
    }

}
```

Code to assign some test data to repeater:

```
public void AssignLanguageListToRepeater()
{
     List<Language> languages = new List<Language>
     {
         new Language{LangID="1", LangName="English"},
         new Language{LangID="2", LangName="Spanish"}
     };
     Repeater1.DataSource = languages;
     Repeater1.DataBind();
}
```

Hope this help you...

Comment: Thanks for an idea. Not exactly what I had in mind but it will do. I will use grid with aspx checkboxes in TemplateField.

Comment: What through me off course was this property for checkboxlist:  RepeatColumns. I never see it in use and thought that it may fit my needs.